# how can i find out the current osx-terminal theme from within a bash script

Tags: macos, bash, scripting, terminal, themes

Inside a bash script, I need to know what the current OS X terminal theme is. How can this be done?

I check the output of the env command, but didn't find anything.

Comment: A bash script runs in a single tab, window. So whats the name of that theme the script wants to know.

Answer (score 4):

We can use an AppleScript to retrieve the name of the profile of the foremost Terminal window from within a bash shell:

```
echo 'tell application "Terminal" to return name of current settings of first window' | osascript
```

We can similarly set the profile:

```
echo 'tell application "Terminal" to set current settings of first window to settings set "Basic"' | osascript
```

Replace "Basic" with the name of the profile you wish to adopt.

These commands will apply to the current/foremost tab or window of Terminal.app

I've also written a script that will get/set the profile depending on whether a profile name is provided: https://github.com/starbase527/dotfiles/blob/master/local/bin/term-profile . Example usage:

```
# Gets profile name
> term-profile
Basic
# Sets profile to Basic
> term-profile Basic
>
```

Answer (score 3):

On a per-shell basis, you can't. You can get the default setting:

```
defaults read com.apple.Terminal "Default Window Settings"
```

Or the new window setting:

```
defaults read com.apple.Terminal "Startup Window Settings"
```

Comment: any way to get the "current" setting ?

Comment: this should be best response

Answer (score -1):

Directly in zsh, you can get the current Terminal.app theme like this:

```
CURRENT_THEME=$(osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to return name of current settings of first window')
echo $CURRENT_THEME
```

From that, and with some AppleScript knowledge, you can get some of the details of the Terminal.app

Happy coding